# How can I get these dialogs informing me that I need to restart to stop popping up?

Tags: bash, debian, notifications

On Debian, I am now getting these messages,

[image: Relogin or restarts required!]

Dialog reads,

> **Relogin or restarts required!** Your session is running obsolete binaries or libraries as listed below. **Please consider a relogin or restart of the affected processes!** bash[pids] sh[pids]

How can I disable these notifications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/needrestart/notify.conf`

Uncomment the line,

```
#NR_NOTIFYD_DISABLE_NOTIFY_SEND='1'
```

So it looks like

```
NR_NOTIFYD_DISABLE_NOTIFY_SEND='1'
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to get rid of the notifications is to restart the affected programs.

The notifications are produced by `needrestart`; if you don’t care about them, you can uninstall the package, or remove the specific notification script, `/etc/needrestart/notify.d/400-notify-send`.