# Debian forced a restart after asking me to restart myself

Tags: debian, kde

**TL;DR:** My Debian workstation forcibly restarted. I think `needrestart` is responsible, but this doesn't make sense.

I'm a little bit miffed, right now; the same problem that Linux users pointed out on Windows just happened on my Debian workstation.

I'm on Debian Sid with KDE installed by default. Out of the blue, I get a notification, saying:

> Relogin or restarts required!
>
> Your session is running obsolete binaries or libraries listed below. [lists processes...]

I decided to hold it off for tonight, but then a few seconds later, another notification pops up. And another one. And another one. Soon, my notifications were flooded:

[image: notify-send]

And a new notification shows every five seconds. I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523536/155357) to another question disabling the notifications by editing `/etc/needrestart/notify.conf`. After I saved the file, it looked like it stopped, but then no more than a minute later, all my programs were replaced with the Debian restart splash screen.

[image: restart by camera]

This restart could not have happened by any of my applications open (I only had Firefox and Discord, maybe some other misc programs), and this happening right after reconfiguring `needrestart` seemed more than coincidental, so I purged that package from my life. I also uninstalled `unattended-upgrades` as well.

Should this be all that I need to do? Would `needrestart` even be responsible for forcibly restarting a workstation? If it was *intentionally* responsible for restarting my workstation, I'd find it concerning that Debian would allow this installed by default. It'd be more believable that this were a mistake by either `needrestart` or some other process behind the scenes. If so, where would I go finding out which process restarted my workstation?